# Default python unittests returns false positives

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-2.7, python-unittest, test-explorer

I have a python 2.7 project in visual studio using the python tools plugin.

I have created a basic test generated by the Visual studio template,

```
import unittest

class Test_test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_A(self):
        self.fail("Not implemented")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The issue I am getting is that if i run the tests through test explorer they pass even though they include the self.fail.

If I debug the tests they will fail without hitting a break on any line of the file.

Has anyone had this issue before or know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: That fails as expected when I run it from the command line. What if you remove the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard?

Comment: running without this included still returns the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue now, the only solution I could find was to uninstall then reinstall the python tools for visual studio.